# Glide-Android- loading (fullscreen) images not working

Tags: android, caching, imageview, fullscreen, android-glide

I am using `Glide` library for loading images in `recyclerview` which works fine. When I click an item, URLs data are sent using intent.

```
//rvFragment   
.
.
.
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(gifUrl[position]).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.mPostIV);
holder.mPostIV.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullScreenImage.class);
                i.putExtra("fsPostIv", gifUrl);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out););
            }
        });
```

everything is OK here, but in `FullScreenImage.class` loading not works.

FullScreenImage.class

```
public class FullScreenImage extends AppCompatActivity{
private TouchImageView imIv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_image);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    imIv=(TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_screen_iv);
    Glide.with(this).load(intent.getExtras().getString("fsPostIv")).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imIv);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}
}
```

When I have not any image loading in `rvFragment` and use images in `drawable` folder, images in `FullScreenImage.class` are shown without any problem. how can i solve this problem. Thank You in Advance.